# Why is my code failling in Rust when I don't declare a variable in the loop

Tags: rust

Code that fails

```
use std::cmp::Ordering;
use std::io;
use rand::Rng;
fn main() {
    println!("Guess the Number!");
    let mut guess = String::new();
    let secret_number = rand::thread_rng().gen_range(1..10);
    loop {

        println!("Please input the guess.");
        io::stdin().read_line(&mut guess).expect("Failed to read line"); 
        let guess: u32 = guess.trim().parse().expect("Please Type a Number");
        println!("You guessed: {}", guess); 
        match guess.cmp(&secret_number) {
            Ordering::Less => println!("Too Small!"),
            Ordering::Greater => println!("Too Large!"),
            Ordering::Equal => println!("You got this"),
        }
    }
}
```

Code that works

```
use std::cmp::Ordering;
use std::io;
use rand::Rng;
fn main() {
    println!("Guess the Number!");
    let secret_number = rand::thread_rng().gen_range(1..10);
    loop {

        println!("Please input the guess.");
        //Now Defining guess Inside the loop  
        let mut guess = String::new();
        io::stdin().read_line(&mut guess).expect("Failed to read line"); 
        let guess: u32 = guess.trim().parse().expect("Please Type a Number");
        println!("You guessed: {}", guess); 
        match guess.cmp(&secret_number) {
            Ordering::Less => println!("Too Small!"),
            Ordering::Greater => println!("Too Large!"),
            Ordering::Equal => println!("You got this"),
        }
    }
}
```

From what I can understand, defining guess each time the loop runs makes my code work, otherwise, I get the error shown below

Why does this happen, I am entering integers only so I should not get a data type mismatch, and why does it work as soon as I start defining guess, again and again, I think this has something to do with how rust handle spaces or newline in input, but not sure.
Any help would be appreciated
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bUtoQ.png)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It failed because each time when you `read_line` it will append the stdin buffer to the `guess` string. So `guess` will change as following.

`1\n` -> `1\n2\n` -> `1\n2\n3\n`

To fix this issue, `clear` the `guess` variable in each loop.

```rust
use std::cmp::Ordering;
use std::io;
use rand::Rng;
fn main() {
    println!("Guess the Number!");
    let mut guess = String::new();
    let secret_number = rand::thread_rng().gen_range(1..10);
    loop {

        println!("Please input the guess.");
        io::stdin().read_line(&mut guess).expect("Failed to read line"); 
        // I renamed it to a different name. Because I want to access the guess string in the end of the loop
        let guess_nmb: u32 = guess.trim().parse().expect("Please Type a Number");
        println!("You guessed: {}", guess_nmb); 
        match guess_nmb.cmp(&secret_number) {
            Ordering::Less => println!("Too Small!"),
            Ordering::Greater => println!("Too Large!"),
            Ordering::Equal => println!("You got this"),
        }
        // Clear the guess string
        guess.clear();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this makes sense!